# attaching a file to email on contact form

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5.3, octobercms

I am trying to create a contact form component that attaches file to contact form and sends the form as an email without saving the file to the server my default.htm is

```
<form data-request="onSend" data-request-success="alert('We have recieved your email.. we\'ll get back to you shortly'); this.reset();" data-request-error="alert(jqXHR.responseText);" class="col s12">
  <input type="text" class="validate" id="first_name" name="first_name">
  <label for="first_name" class="active">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name">
  <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
  <input type="email" class="validate" id="email" name="email">
  <label data-success="right" data-error="wrong" for="email">Email</label>
  <textarea id="textarea1" name="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
  <label for="textarea1">Description</label>
  <select multiple name="value[]">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
  </select>
  <label>Choose Option</label>
      <span>File</span>
      <input name="resume" type="file">
      <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload one or more files">
  <label for="datepicker">Set the Date</label>
  <input type="date" class="datepicker" id="datepicker" name="datepicker">
  <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" checked="checked" />
  <label for="filled-in-box">Send copy to my email</label>
  <button class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit<i class="material-icons right">send</i></button>
```

my ContactForm.php has

```
    <?php namespace Pft\Contact\Components;

 use Cms\Classes\ComponentBase;
 use Input;
 use Mail;
 use Validator;
 use Redirect;
 use ValidationException;

 class ContactForm extends ComponentBase
 {
    /**
      * Returns information about this component, including name and description.
      */
     public function componentDetails()
     {
         return
         [
            'name' => 'Contact Form',
            'description' => 'A Contact form for Laratify Octaskin theme'
         ];
     }
     function onSend()
     {
        $data = post();
        $rules = 
         [
             'first_name' => 'required|min:5',
             'last_name' => 'required|min:3',
             'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
             'textarea1' => 'required'
         ];      
        $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);        
         if ($validator->fails()){
                // do something
             throw new ValidationException($validator);
         }else {
             // These variables are available inside the message as Twig
             $vars = [
                        'first_name' =>  Input::get('first_name'),
                        'last_name' => Input::get('last_name'),
                        'email' => Input::get('email'),
                        'textarea1' =>  Input::get('textarea1'),
                        'datepicker' =>  Input::get('datepicker'),
                        'value' =>  Input::get('value'),    
                        'resume' =>  Input::get('resume'),                      
                    ];          
             Mail::send('yourappname.website::mail.contactform', $vars, function ($message)  {
                $message->to('youremail', ' Admin Person');
                $message->subject('New Contact');
                $message->attach( Input::file('resume') );
             });
         }
     }
 }
```

but I get and error back saying "The path cannot be empty" I not sure what path as I don't wish to save the file to the server